# I need help, my class wont get the data from my data base

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

```
public class ActivityList extends Activity {

    SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_list);

        db = new SQLiteHandler(this);

        BackGroundTask backGroundTask = new BackGroundTask(this);
        backGroundTask.execute("get_info");
        //populateActivityList();
        registerClickCallBack();
    }

    private void registerClickCallBack()
    {
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listActivities);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                try{
                    String name = (String) list.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    NewActivityDB activities = db.changeStatus(name);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityList.this,OnGoingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("activity",activities);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //finish();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityList.this, "ActivityView: "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I need help in getting the data from the data base.It wont display the create activity..here is the error via image

[image: demo]

Comment: your changeStatus() method returns String .

Comment: what do you mean sir? please be specific

Comment: In Screen Shot there is 'ClassCastException' comes  in  this line. NewActivityDB activities = db.changeStatus(name);this

Answer (score 1):

This line in your code: `NewActivityDB activities = db.changeStatus(name);` is causing it.
And the exception means: You're trying to assign a String value to an entity object. So changing that line should fix your problem. So basically db.changeStatus(name) is returning a string and that you are trying to assign it to an object, hence the ClassCastException

Comment: ah sir.. what should i put into it aside from db.changeStatus(name)

Comment: `changeStatus(name)` : Is that the method that you've written? You can try to return an object of NewActivityDB in that instead of returning a String, or better could you post your method out here? So I could find any hints.